# How do I get the dates in a date range in Sharepoint

Tags: calendar

IE Start Date: 10/1/2017 End Date : 10/5/2017 Duration : 5

Would like result like this: 10/1/2017; 10/2/2017; 10/3/2017; 10/4/2017; 10/5/2017

Comment: Is this in a view, via REST, using a CAML query, something else? More details will give you a better shot at getting an answer, thanks!

Comment: I would like to store the values in a text field delimited by a comma or semi-colon.  The start and end date are picked from a calendar on an InfoPath form.  I tried using a loop action in Nintex, but it stopped after the forth loop and is very slow